# Querying temporal table with date/time fields

Tags: sql-server, temporal-tables

I need to write a query to get following output using temporal table feature in SQL server 2016.

Customer Table (system versioned table)

```
Id
Name
[period_start] [datetime2](7) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START NOT NULL
[period_end] [datetime2](7) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END NOT NULL
```

Orders Table

```
Id
CustomerId
..
[creation_date] DATETIME default SYSUTCDATETIME()
```

Output : OrderId, ... , Customer Name

Customer name should be the reflect the correct name which relevant to the order date

Following query will give me the required output but I need to check whether this is the correct way of doing this type of queries..

```
SELECT T.Id, O.Name
FROM Orders T
INNER JOIN (
SELECT *
FROM Customer 
FOR SYSTEM_TIME FROM '1900-01-01' TO '9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999'
) O ON T.CustomerId = O.ID 
AND T.creation_date BETWEEN O.period_start AND O.period_end
```

Thanks in advance

Chaminda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see nothing wrong with it, except perhaps the nested query is unnecessary:

```
SELECT T.Id, O.Name
FROM Orders T
JOIN Customer FOR SYSTEM_TIME FROM '1900-01-01' TO '9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999' O 
    ON T.CustomerId = O.ID 
WHERE T.creation_date BETWEEN O.period_start AND O.period_end
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I thought, hard coding time period may not be good thing in my query. I'm wondering whether they have any specific syntax for doing this type of common scenarios

Comment: temporal tables are relatively new (in sql server), so there are not that many common scenarios around. You can replace the dates with variables if that's what you mean. All in all I think you worry too much. Ask (yourself) a question if something doesn't work or becomes too slow.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have extraneous criteria in your query.  I think this does everything you've asked for:

```
SELECT T.Id, O.Name
FROM Orders T INNER JOIN Customer O 
ON T.CustomerId = O.ID
```

Comment: Hi Wayne, This will always return the current Customer name, not the past names that order was placed.

Comment: @Cham - Is there a Customer name field on the _Orders_ table?